# using root for pentesting and non-root for normal use

Tags: sudo, root

So i know it's bad to run as root for normal usage, but for some usecases such as pentesting it's actually a pain to not run as root.
I'm running on ubuntu gnome with all the kali repos added in for the tooling. I'm not new to linux but im only about mildly experienced with pentesting.

Would it be bad to have normal user (user sign in I use for everyday stuff) as non root, then sign in as root for pentesting? Running as non-root is a pain, I end up with files I have to `chown` constantly, programs which will only run as root due to it needs access to direct from the wire and having to enter my password every five seconds.

Answer (score 0):

> would it be bad normal user (user sign in i use for everyday stuff) as
>   non root, then sign in as root for pentesting?

No. That sounds about right. But... if it were up to me, I would run Ubuntu as my "normal" distribution, and run Kali Linux in [Live mode](http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install) off of a USB stick when doing the pentesting.

Adding repos from other distributions can become a real pain in the you-know-where and cause major headaches.

Comment: i know about the repos, i have been running on linux for about 7 years now. I was semi smart about it, i add the repo, installed the tools, then removed. generated a script to add it back in when checking for updates for those tools only. leaves me safe from accidentally updating down the paths of two distos at once. also personally i like to have everything i use in one place, not have to reboot and go to live boot just for a tool.

Comment: If that is your preferred method, then by all means go for it!